# MATLAB GUI to set Object Constructor

Tags: matlab, class, user-interface, oop, io

I'm currently designing a GUI to open a MAT file(s) to store the time-series variables in it as properties in a class, and do things to the data within the class. The Class is pretty well defined, however, it is the I/O portion of it that I need guidance on.

The constructor of the class currently is written to set the properties to empty if there are no inputs. However, I have a method that has a UIOPEN to get the file and set the properties of the class.

I have created a GUIDE GUI, where I pass the empty object of the class to the handles of the GUI and store it using guidata. The GUI has a button (along with other elements) called "Get File" that will call the property setter method when clicked to populate the properties and a listbox with those properties.

The uncertainty is in the whole architecture of what I have done. I'd like to know if there is a better way to accomplish this. It seems like it's kind of a mickey mouse way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can point out a few things:

- `GUIDE` is old, weird and it is generally better to create GUIs programmatically
- once you have gotten rid of `GUIDE` you can have the object govern the GUI behavior easily - the object could have methods to spawn and refresh the gui, hold handles to gui elements in private properties etc.
- Creating object-manged guis can also save you some problems with syncing workspace with the gui without using `global`, `assignin` or `evalin`. Since the object holds the data and it also governs the gui - the problem is no longer present.
- Mathworks [disencourages](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102591-what-is-the-difference-between-application-data-guidata-and-userdata-in-matlab) using `guidata` for things other than handles to graphical objects, and advices the user to use `appdata`